# Excel VBA create columns and populate with data based on another column

Tags: vba, excel

Okay so I have to create two new columns and populate it with data from another worksheet if **the values for another column matches**. I'll break it up to make it easier to understand. There are two worksheets namely; "JULY15Release_Dev status" and "JULY '15 Rel". 
Both of these worksheets have a header of "eRequest ID" for column A. I need to create two new columns for "JULY15Release_Dev status" and populate it with data from "JULY '15 Rel" if the "eRequest ID" matches for that specific row of data.

By **creating two new columns and populating it with data**, it doesn't necessarily have to be "creating then populating", copying that exact 2 columns is also fine, so long as the data remain intact. The data will be in date/time format if it affects anything.  Thanks in advance for any help as I'm a total beginner at this!

Comment: Take a look at VLOOKUP.

Comment: VLOOKUP doesnt work.. I need to match the "eRequest ID" on both worksheets, and then copy two columns of data from `July 15 Rel` to `Release Dev Status`. and the data needs to correspond to their "eRequest ID" as well, since the number of rows of data in both worksheets are unequal.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, before we do `VLOOKUP`, our `JULY15Release_Dev status` sheet looks like this:

```
   A          B          C
1 eRequestID  FirstName  Lastname
2 10
3 30
```

`JULY '15 Rel` looks like this:

```
   A          B          C         D ....
1 eRequestID  FirstName  Lastname  Age
2 10          Jon        Smith     40
3 20          Matt       Kahn      50
```

Our task is to get FirstName and Lastname from `JULY '15 Rel` into `JULY15Release_Dev status`.

After adding `VLOOKUP` in `JULY15Release_Dev status`, the sheet looks like this:

```
   A          B                                                        C
1 eRequestID  FirstName                                                Lastname
2 10          =VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,'JULY ''15 Rel'!$A$1:$C$3,2,FALSE)    =VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,'JULY ''15 Rel'!$A$1:$C$3,3,FALSE)
3 30          =VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A3,'JULY ''15 Rel'!$A$1:$C$3,2,FALSE)    =VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A3,'JULY ''15 Rel'!$A$1:$C$3,3,FALSE)
```

Give it a shot and see how it works for you.

Comment: Nope, it is not working. Just to clarify, the number of rows of data in both worksheets are unequal. I have to match the "eRequest ID" from the rows of both `July 15 Rel` and `Release Dev Status`. If it matches, I have to **copy two specific columns of data** from `Release Dev Status` over to `July 15 Rel`. Also, the values for both columns are in date format. Hope this helps!

Comment: @JunJie I have uploaded [a sample](http://zedfox.us/projects/stackoverflow/30115403.xlsx). Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to answer with diagram

```
=INDEX(Sheet!A:1:1048576, MATCH(A2, 'JULY ''15 Rel'$A:$A,0),[column number])
```

no data sort necessary
if you want to put it into a macro it is a bit redundant unless used based on other variables or tasks.