# Excel VBA copy column data if another column data matches

Tags: vba, date, excel

Okay I previously posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115403/excel-vba-create-columns-and-populate-with-data-based-on-another-column/30115682#30115682) but I realized it may be vague and many people may not understand so I'm posting again to clarify things. I have two worksheets, namely; `JULY ' 15 Rel` and `Release Dev Status`.

Both of these worksheets have a column heading of "eRequest ID" in column A. I have to copy **two columns, "Dev / UT Plan End Date" and "Dev / UT Actual End Date" from `Release Dev Status` over to `JULY ' 15 Rel`** when the "eRequest ID" of both worksheets matches.

For eg: if there is a record with "eRequest ID" of 41316 in both worksheets, then I need to copy the "Dev / UT Plan End Date" and "Dev / UT Actual End Date" data for record 41316 **in `Release Dev Status` over to `JULY '15 Rel`**

I was previously asked to use the VLOOKUP function but I tried it out and I don't think it'll work as the number of rows in both data are uneven. Pardon me as I dont have any codes for you guys to start off with, I have no idea how to start this at all...

Also if this helps, the data would be in this format "22/04/2015" for example. Also, apart from Column A which is "eRequest ID", the other columns in both worksheets are different. It may have the same heading but definitely in different orders. Thank you guys in advance for helping out!

Comment: Please paste example data from ALL 2 worksheets. "Release Dev Status" and the TOBE "JULY ' 15 Rel"

Comment: I can't upload any files from my office as my company's really strict regarding this, nor can I share it from home as the files would be encrypted. I took some pictures instead, hope this helps. [this](http://imgur.com/m5iycem) shows my current `JULY ' 15 Rel` sheet and [this](http://imgur.com/cE09IB7) shows my current `Release Dev Status` sheet. [this](http://imgur.com/XivR1qZ) is an example of the data that is to be copied from `Release Dev Status` over to `JULY ' 15 Rel` Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just like in your previous post this **the answer would be a `VLOOKUP` formula in both columns:**

Dev UT End Date:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;'Release Dev Status'!A$1:Z$1000;COLUMN($I$1);FALSE)
```

Dev UT Actual Date:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;'Release Dev Status'!A$1:Z$1000;COLUMN(J$1);FALSE)
```

Change the range `'Release Dev Status'!A$1:Z$1000` appropriately.

Comment: Is it alright if i set the range to be `,'JULY15Release_Dev status'!$1:$1048576`? Also, do I have to change the column according to the one in `Release Dev Status`? or is it supposed to be the new column in `July ' 15 Rel`? Sorry if I'm asking really basic questions, I'm new to VBA and Excel in general and am not familiar with most of the functions.